# Segmentation fault (core dumped) Openmpi.4.0.0

Tags: segmentation-fault, mpi, openmpi

I installed Open MPI 4.0.0, and it seemed to be okay. But when I tried to run the example hello_c in example files, it not works. I put on terminal

```
 mpirun -np 4 hello_c
```

And I get the following error back:

```
[gabriel-Inspiron-5558] *** Process received signal ***
[gabriel-Inspiron-5558] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[gabriel-Inspiron-5558] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[gabriel-Inspiron-5558] Failing at address: (nil)
[gabriel-Inspiron-5558] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x46210)[0x7f00bf512210]
[gabriel-Inspiron-5558] *** End of error message ***
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What can I do to correct this?

Comment: Hi, could you add your hello_c code as well

Comment: How did you install Open MPI? try the latest (`4.0.5` or `4.1.1`)